# Trying to update posgres database in docker resulting in machine refusing connection

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

While doing first database update i get an error

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>      at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
>      at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
>      at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I'm using Docker Toolbox for low end pc. And I ran postgres container with command:

`docker run --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres;`

For connecting EF Core to pgsql I used Npgsql nuget package and connectionString

`"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password"`

Next, I created in MyDbContext file

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}


public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password");

        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

After which i added dbContext in Startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
    services.AddDbContext<Models.MyDbContext>();
```

Can anyone help me, or suggest what could I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, `Server=127.0.0.1` will work when you start your .net core project from host.

I assume you start your .net core project from docker, if so, you need to follow steps belwo which connect the two container.

1. Change your connectionstring with postgres container name `pg` like

   ```
   "Server=pg;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password"
   ```
2. Specify the `--link=pg` while running the .net core like

   ```
   docker run -it -p 8585:80 --link=pg dockerpostgres
   ```